# OQL: Tomcat threads with retained heap

Tags: oql, eclipse-mat

I'm having trouble with joining two OQL statements. Since the sub select syntax in OQL is a little quirky could someone help me out?

#### Select 1

```
SELECT thread.name.toString(), thread.@retainedHeapSize 
FROM java.lang.Thread thread
```

Will return a result set with 2 columns: thread name | retained heap size

#### Select 2

```
SELECT toString(info.workerThreadName), toString(info.req.queryMB.byteC.buff) 
FROM org.apache.coyote.RequestInfo info
```

Will also return a result set with 2 columns: thread name | the request uri

### Question

How can I join these into a single select with 3 columns?

So the result would be: thread name | request uri | retained heap size

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Eclipse OQL supports joins, so you are left with two distinct results that you can export and join using external tools. E.g., you can use [`csvjoin`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/scripts/csvjoin.html) from [`csvkit`](https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit) python tool to make this simple.